# Using Hexadecimal to represent a 7 bit code

Tags: hex, ascii, bit

My computer uses ASCII, American Standard Code for Information Exchange.
It is my understanding that this uses a 7 bit code to represent all the letters, symbols, and numbers needed for the english language.

It is my understanding that these 7 bits can be represented with hexadecimal codes. 
I thought that hexadecimal needed 8 bits. 4 bits per number.

Can some one explain to me how the hexadecimal system can be used to represent the codes in the 7 bit ASCII system.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hexadecimal numbers don't *need* eight bits, each hex digit can represent four bits but there's no upper limit, since you can just use more digits:

```
0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff...
```

For representing seven-bit values, you can just use the lower half of the eight-bit hex numbers, `0x00` through `0x7f`.

That gives you the binary numbers `0000000` through `1111111`.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine any combination of up to 4 bits into one hexadecimal character.

```
1 bit:  0 to 1
2 bits: 0 to 3 
3 bits: 0 to 7
4 bits: 0 to F
```

For 7 bits you need 2 hex digit, one coding 3 bits and the other 4 bits so you get a code of 00 to 7F.

Or you use 8 bits, but the most significant bit is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

With 7 bits you can represent every number from 0 to 2^7 = 127 (decimal) = 7f (hexadecimal).

Hexadecimal doesn't *need* 7 bits, it is just another way to write numbers.